# How to work in TYPO3 with external JSON File

Tags: json, typo3, extbase

Hi i've searched a while now. How is it possible to get data from a JSON file and work with the data in an extbase extension?

Comment: of course it is. Would you mind sharing your use case so we can help you?

Comment: I have an external app. I would like to create a list of options like "articles", "orders" and so on in an backend extension. If a user select article it shoult trigger the third party application. You should get the link www.domain.com/articles <- JSON an then output the result.

Comment: So, your TYPO3 instance should provide data for the app, right? And which data it displays should rely on the (JSON-encoded) request? Your TYPO3 instance should act as an API endpoint. One concept would be using REST API with the TYPO3 as the server.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is simply another, non-database storage. So handling should be the same as with storing/using XML. And that was some days ago discussed in another (solved) thread on SO:

"[Show xml data in Frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434723/show-xml-data-in-frontend)"

Comment: Thank you, i have to figure it out how to get JSON data from an external source or an application within the fileadmin folder